# Vlookup returns wrong results near bottom of sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table like this:

[image]

I need to look up the text in **column A**, and find an appropriate result for it, and place that in **column B**.

So I created a new reference list, and it looks like this:

[image]

This is the formula I used in **Columns B**

```
=VLOOKUP(B1, MyList, 2)
```

It appears to work OK at first, however once I got past *result5*, my code was only able to show the result "result5". Something like this:

[image]

I don't know why this is. My true list is larger and has over 13,000 rows.

Thanks

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(B1, MyList, 2,False)`

Comment: Wow, thanks.Please add it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behaviour of VLOOKUP is to assume that the first column is in order and return the closest match.  Adding FALSE as a fourth parameter, or sorting the first column will fix this, depending on whether you need an exact match, or are happy with the closest match.