# VLOOKUP returning "7 meses" as the match for "12 meses"

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I'm trying to use `VLOOKUP()` on Google Sheets to return the value on the second column that is in the same row as the key fed into the function.

I'm bewildered by the computation error coming out of it, which is illustrated in the screenshot below.

[image]

How come it returns "12 meses" as the match for "7 meses"?

I discovered that because i was first trying to get vlookup to return "210" and it kept returning "360" --- by changing the index to 1, i realized it's indeed somehow matching "7 meses" to "12 meses" and i can't work out why :-(

The more i try to debug it, the more confused i get. For instance, by replacing "7 meses" by "almondega" and searching for "7 meses" it then returns "6 meses":

[image]

Mind blown!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vlookup returns wrong results near bottom of sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948597/vlookup-returns-wrong-results-near-bottom-of-sheet)

Answer (score 1):

Add the last, optional argument as 0. Then it will work fine:

```
=VLOOKUP("7 meses";duracaoExpandido;1;0)
```

**Explanation:**

As Google Offical doc says: is_sorted - [optional]
Indicates whether the column to be searched (the first column of the specified range) is sorted, in which case the closest match for search_key will be returned. [Link](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)